# Elasticsearch Aggregation sort not working on terms sub-aggregation

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch, aggregation

**I have a requirement to sort the first level aggregation based on second level aggregation.**

The above scenario works perfectly fine when the second level aggregation is either cardinality/sum/max etc.., which is related to a number, but when I add terms under second level aggregation an excepection is being thrown :

**MY QUERY :**

```
> {   
>     "size": 0,
>     "aggs": {
>     "id": {
>       "terms": {
>         "field": "column_id.keyword",
>         "size": 10,
>         "order": {
>           "sort": "asc"
>         }
>       },
>       "aggs": {
>         "sort": {
>           "terms": {
>             "field": "table_name.keyword",
>             "size": 10
>           }
>         }
>       }
>     } 
>   }
> }
```

**Exception from ES :**

Invalid terms aggregation order path [sort]. Terms buckets can only be sorted on a sub-aggregator path that is built out of zero or more single-bucket aggregations within the path and a final single-bucket or a metrics aggregation at the path end.

**By looking at the above message I understand sort wont work on terms, but is there any way I can sort the first level aggregation based on second field of type text or keyword??**

Comment: As per the error message, the sub-aggregation must either be a single-bucket terms aggregation (i.e. size = 1) or a metric sub-aggregation (min, max, etc)

Comment: I'm not sure about what you want to achieve, since sort is not a single value, but a map of up to 10 `table_name.keyword` keys with its `doc_count`. Why don't you post an example of your desired result?

Comment: May you add few example documents and illustrate how they should be grouped and sorted?

Comment: @Val Even setting the size to one does not help

Comment: @JosuGoñi I wanted the results in following manner
`
A
  {COLUMN1,
  COLUMN2}
B
   {COLUMN1,
   COLUMN2}
`
Where A and B are table names which are sorted

Comment: Then you don't want to sort based on the second level aggregation.

Answer (score 1):

Change sort to _key

```
>     {   
    >     "size": 0,
    >     "aggs": {
    >     "id": {
    >       "terms": {
    >         "field": "column_id.keyword",
    >         "size": 10,
    >         "order": {
    >           "_key": "asc"
    >         }
    >       },
    >       "aggs": {
    >         "sort": {
    >           "terms": {
    >             "field": "table_name.keyword",
    >             "size": 10
    >           }
    >         }
    >       }
    >     } 
    >      }
    >      }
```